# Smooth scroll automatically starts on page load

Tags: css, smooth-scrolling

I am new to programming. I wanted to create a smooth scrolling effect when I click on an href on my page, to do so I have used the scroll behavior:smooth in css. I've applied the rule like this

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Otherwise it works great, but there's a consequence that I do not wish is there, on page load it automatically smooth scrolls to the identifier that's applied onto the href. I want to avoid this, how can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = "html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it's not working for me. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Uhmm it did for me, maybe do that inside a 2sec timeout?

Comment: I've actually tried it, added other code as well. 
if (history.scrollRestoration) {
  history.scrollRestoration = "manual";
} else {
  window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  };
}

window.onload = function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var node = document.createElement("style");
    node.innerHTML = "html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}";
    document.body.appendChild(node);
  }, 1000);
};
It works some times, some times it doesn't for some reason. Good enough haha, thanks.